# Saving Python SymPy figures with a specific resolution/pixel density

Tags: python, sympy

I am wondering if there is a way to change the pixel density/resolution of sympy plots. For example, let's consider the simple code snippet below:

```
import sympy as syp

x = syp.Symbol('x')
miles_to_km = x * 1.609344
miles_to_km.evalf()

graph = syp.plot(miles_to_km, show=False)
graph.save('./figures/miles_to_km.png')
graph.show()
```

[image]

### Notes:

- When I tried using `graph.savefig`, I got an `AttributeError: 'Plot' object has no attribute 'saveimage'` I stumbled upon the `saveimage` method in some online resource, and it sounded like that this was the common approach -- I guess the API changed?
- `graph.save('./figures/miles_to_km.png', dpi=300)` produces a type error: `TypeError: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dpi'`
- Using the `dpi` attribute in `plot` does not throw any error but doesn't affect the image quality either: `graph = syp.plot(miles_to_km, dpi=300, show=False)`

I also tried using the matplotlib backend:

```
plt.figure()
graph = syp.plot(miles_to_km, show=False)
#graph.save('./figures/miles_to_km.png')
plt.savefig('./figures/miles_to_km.png')
graph.show()
```

where `plt` = `matplotlib.pyplot`. However, the canvas is blank. Also relevant info may be that I am running it in an IPython notebook with `%matplotlib inline` enabled.

- I am using SymPy v. 0.7.6

the `backend` workaround below shows the plot in the IPython notebook, but it also produces a white canvas (as png)

```
graph = syp.plot(miles_to_km, show=False)
backend = graph.backend(graph)
backend.fig.savefig('ch01_2.png', dpi=300)
backend.show()
```

[image]

### EDIT and Solution:

Thanks to [Cody Piersall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1612701/cody-piersall)'s answer the issue is now resolved. I updated to IPython 4.0 (Jupyter notebook) and plotted it as follows

```
graph = syp.plot(miles_to_km, show=False)
backend = graph.backend(graph)
backend.process_series()
backend.fig.savefig('miles_to_km.png', dpi=300)
backend.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the matplotlib backend, which is the default if you have matplotlib installed, you just have to `import matplotlib.pyplot` and use [`pyplot.savefig`](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.savefig).

This works because sympy uses matplotlib to do its plotting, and since matplotlib is stateful, it knows which plot you're working with.

Here is your example, but using savefig to save to a png.

```
import sympy as syp

x = syp.Symbol('x')
miles_to_km = x * 1.609344
miles_to_km.evalf()

graph = syp.plot(miles_to_km, show=False)

# Does not work in IPython Notebook, but works in a script.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.savefig('./figures/miles_to_km.png', dpi=300)
```

If you are in an IPython notebook, the above will not work, but you can still save them with a specified dpi. You just have to be a little tricky about it.

```
# works in IPython Notebook
backend = graph.backend(graph)
ackend.fig.savefig('300.png', dpi=300)
backend.fig.savefig('20.png', dpi=20)
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention that I tried that too, but the canvas is just blank. Even if I instantiate a `plt.figure()` prior to the sympy plot. Maybe I should mention that I am running it in an IPython notebook using the interactive mode

Comment: @SebastianRaschka Ah!  It works whenever it's in a script, but I just tried it in an IPython notebook too and it didn't work.  I'm not sure why...

Comment: Hm, maybe it's a bug or another quirk of the interactive mode. Anyways, let's see if someone has an idea, if not, I will open an issue in the github repo. It's not so super important right now, but it would be extremely handy for me. Just started working on a new book and I like having the IPython notebooks as additional resource for the reader while I want to use the images in the book body itself.

Comment: @SebastianRaschka I've got a workaround that you can use to your heart's desire.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick tip, but I still have the "blank" png problem when I use this approach. Maybe I am missing something? I posted the code above.

Comment: @SebastianRaschka maybe restart the Notebook kernel?  It works for me on Python 3.4 on Ubuntu, but I was seeing the same problem as you with blank pngs earlier. :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87626/discussion-between-cody-piersall-and-sebastian-raschka).

Comment: Answer worked great. Perhaps it'd be helpful to add the solution in the answer as well; I missed it when reading the question :)

Answer (score 3):

This problem has been fixed, you can now simply use this:

```
graph = sympy.plot(f, show = False)
graph.save('fig.png')
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to allow for the selection of a dpi.